# SharePoint: How to capture the Click event for the Close link on the WebPart menu?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to overwrite the behaviour of the Close link on the WebPart dropdown menu so that I can delete the webpart from the page instead of closing them.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

No need for an event handler - just set the AllowClose property of the part to False. This can be done in code, in the .webpart file, or by editing of the settings of the part using the browser.